# Create JSON for chart Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

**I want to create a dummy json data and use it for highChart.
This is how I am creating  json array**

```
var summaryData = {
                    WestWorld:[
                        {"Jan":7894},
                        {"Feb":7845},
                        {"March":5826},
                        {"April":7930},
                        {"May":1589},
                        {"June":7891},
                        {"July":9724},
                        {"August":7403},
                        {"September":5566},
                        {"October":7733},
                        {"November":1186},
                        {"December":4456}
                    ],
                    EastWorld:[
                        {"Jan":7410},
                        {"Feb":9512},
                        {"March":7520},
                        {"April":8510},
                        {"May":9965},
                        {"June":72580},
                        {"July":147},
                        {"August":4489},
                        {"September":6685},
                        {"October":7036},
                        {"November":8852},
                        {"December":4569}
                        ]
                };
```

**Now I intend to use this data for drawing charts.I am able to retrieve the keys by doing so**

```
for (var key in summaryData){
        console.log(summaryData[''+key+'']);    
        }
```

**It is consoling an two arrays each of twelve objects.
Can I create this json object in a better way & minimize the if & for loop to get it's keys & value**

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your JSON like so:

```
var summaryData = {
    WestWorld: {
        "Jan":7894,
        "Feb":7845,
        ...
    },
    EastWorld: {
        "Jan":7410,
        "Feb":9512,
        ...
    }    
};
```

This way you can access anything directly, without having to loop through the arrays in `WestWorld` and `EastWorld`. For example:

```
summaryData.WestWorld.Jan => 7894
```

Answer (score 0):

summaryData has two objects that are arrays and in this case array of objects.
This will retrieve one array and its length

```
console.log((summaryData.EastWorld).length);
```

Show the first array element which is an object with a single key:value

```
console.log(summaryData.EastWorld[0]);
```

to get its value

```
console.log(summaryData.EastWorld[0].Jan);
```

A function to retrieve each key:value pair

```
function show(world) {
var len = (summaryData[world]).length;
var obj = "";
var ii = 0;
for (ii; ii < len; ii += 1) {
    obj = summaryData[world][ii];
    for (var key in obj) {
        console.log(key + ' ==> ' + obj[key]);
    }
}
}
show("WestWorld");
show("EastWorld");
```

To be a true JSON each string need to be double quoted
check with an online JSON Validation..